# Change the OpenDaylight Berrylium Openflow port

Tags: opendaylight

I want to change the opendaylight Berrylium  controller's openflow port from 6633 to i.e 6666.

I tried to find the **config.ini** but i couldn't locate it. I'm not even sure if this is the file where I can apply the necessary change.

How can I achieve this.

Any help woud be appreciated.

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

The config.ini file existed in ODL-Helium; I don't believe it exists in ODL-Beryllium.

For ODL-Be, when I changed the OF listen port from 6633 to 6653, I edited the `etc/custom.properties` and changed the `of.listenPort=6633` value to `of.listenPort=6653`. Changing the value to 6666 should work for you.